# What is the neat approach to combining the date and time value (both of datetime type)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I am writing a SQL query on table that has 2 columns:

- StartDate: type - datetime (example: 2022-01-22 00:00:00.000)
- StartTime: type - datetime (example: 1900-01-01 21:30:00.000)

I want to combine both so as to get the datetime value (example: 2022-01-22 21:30:00.000)

I tried using the DATEADD function, but that expects an interval, which is not suitable for my requirement.

I also tried adding the dates using the + sign which seems to give correct result; and also tried converting the date to int and then doing the + followed by conversion to datetime. This doesn't give correct result.

What is the neat approach to combining the date and time value?

Comment: Why are your columns `StartDate` and `StartTime` not a `date` and `time` respectively, considering that neither wants to other portion of the other?

Comment: I am working on a legacy database, and don't have control over the columns. I need to query and understand that + works, just wanted to know whether it works deterministically and is the most recommended approach?

Comment: So what's wrong with `+`? You're using the old `datetime` data types so it works. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6ccd5a5cd27ef21e33656a13a63f4ffa)

Comment: *"don't have control over the columns"* Then speak to whomever does; `date` and `time` have been around for *14 years*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add the two parts, since the reference date for `datetime` is `1900-01-01`. I.e., internally SQL-Server represents it by the number `0`.

```sql
select
    StartDate, StartTime,
    StartDate + StartTime as StartDateTime
from t
```

See: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f0a7/2/0

The documentation for [datetime (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) just says

> Default value  1900-01-01 00:00:00

and

> When the conversion is from time(n), the time component is copied, and the date component is set to '1900-01-01'.

Comment: Just our of interest when I do `CONVERT(INT,StartTime)` - it doesn't give me an intelligible value. Why is that?

Comment: @variable Try `convert(float, StartTime)`. As an INT it gets rounded to 1.

Comment: The date is represented as the number of days since (or before) 1900-01-01, the time is represented as the fractional part. Example 06:00 = 0.25, 12:00 = 0.5, 18:00 = 0.75